# how to test jquery-ui datepicker with Qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, qunit

I'm kind of new to Qunit, and would like to ask a question.

I have created a JavaScript file to simply use datepicker like below, and created a test-code using Qunit.
What I want to do is to show the calendar and select a date, and assert that date has been selected.
My problem here is that I was able to show the calendar, by `.trigger("focus")` but couldn't select anything.

Does anyone know how I can do this??

*datepicker-basic.js*

```js
$(function () {
  $('#jquery-ui-datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

*test-datepicker.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <title>test datepicker.js</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit/qunit-2.0.1.css">

   <script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery-ui/i18n/datepicker-ja.js"></script>

   <script src="qunit/qunit-2.0.1.js"></script>

   <script src="../samples/jquery-ui/js/datepicker-basic.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery.simulate/jquery.simulate.js"></script>
   <script src="test-datepicker.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="qunit"></div>
   <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>

   <input type="text" id="jquery-ui-datepicker">
 </body>
</html>
```

*test-datepicker.js*

```js
QUnit.test( "basic", function( assert ) {
  // initiate input value
  $("#jquery-ui-datepicker").val("");

  // focus on input-textbox and select date on calendar
  $("#jquery-ui-datepicker").trigger("focus").
   simulate( "keydown", { keyCode: $.ui.keyCode.ENTER } );

  // get selected date from input-textbox
  var actual = document.getElementById("jquery-ui-datepicker").value;
  // create expected value
  var today = new Date();
  var expected = formatDate(today);

  // assert
  assert.ok(actual === expected, "selected value from calendar correctly");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I think I found the answer.
I had to add a `trigger.("focus")`.
Here's what I changed, and it worked.

before:

```
  // focus on input-textbox and select date on calendar
  $("#jquery-ui-datepicker").trigger("focus").
      simulate( "keydown", { keyCode: $.ui.keyCode.ENTER } );
```

after:

```
  // focus on input-textbox
  $("#jquery-ui-datepicker").trigger("focus");
  // select date on calendar
  $("#jquery-ui-datepicker").trigger("focus").
      simulate( "keydown", { keyCode: $.ui.keyCode.ENTER } );
```